# vpython 7 with jupyter notebook kernel jump between busy and idle

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vpython

I am trying to run a simple ball moving demo program using vpython 7 on jupyter notebook, however, the ball didn't move smoothly, but like jumping from one position to the next position, there are big delays between frames. I ran the same code in glowscript.org, it demonstrated very smooth motions. After I start the cell, the statue of the jupyter notebook kernel quickly jumps between busy and idle, even if the loop ends, it still jumping. If I interrupt that kernel, the notebook prompt kernel's have died and I have to restart the kernel. I believe this reason results in the delays of the 3D render of the vpython.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, python 2.7, vpython 7.2.0, jupyter notebook 4.2.3 and chrome.

Comment: So what's the problem ? Do you have any codeblocks OR error logs for  debugging ? Read the SO wiki on [how to ask question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try running some of the demo jupyter vpython notebooks in the Demo directory on the github repository for "jupyter vpython" . See if your problem still persists when running these demo vpython notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

Click on this link for the Demo jupyter vpython notebooks that you can run from the cloud in your browser.

https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/BruceSherwood/vpython-jupyter/master?filepath=Demos

It might take a few seconds to launch but you should see the jupyter notebook directory appear in your browser. Open and run any of these notebooks in your browser which run on a remote server in the cloud and compare the performance with what you get from running these vpython demos locally on your machine.